# Parser for simple expression in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
parseExp( ExpToParse, Op(Operand1, Operand2)) :-
    operand(ExpToParse, Diff, Operand1),
    operator(Diff, Diff2, Op),
    operand(Diff2, _, Operand2).

operand([H|L], L, H).
operator(['+'|R], R, add).
operator(['-'|R], R, sub).
operator(['*'|R], R, mul).
operator(['/'|R], R, div).
```

I am trying to implement parser for **simple** expressions, I mean something like: `2 + 4` etc.

But, I got the compiler error in the first line:

```
Syntax error: Operator expected
```

I cannot understand. I want to the second argument of the first term (`Operator(Operand1, Operand2)`) will be unified to `add( 2, 4)`. I mean:

`parseExp( [2, '+', 4] , X ).`
`?- X = add(2,4)`

I don't undersant why a compiler has a problem.

And the second issue:

I know about DCG but I don't use it now because I as you can see I have a problem with understanding difference list. So, you are welcome to say someting about my code in that context.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just a couple of typos: `parseExp( ExpToParse, operator(Operand1, Operand2) ) :- ...`

Comment: You right. But I edited my post. The problem is the same still.

Comment: The error message should tell you a line number. Check that line,or at least say what line it is, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to write `Op(Operand1, Operand2)` like in:

```
parseExp( ExpToParse, Op(Operand1, Operand2)) :- 
  ...
```

instead, use:

```
parseExp( ExpToParse, RES) :- 
  ...,
  RES =.. [ Op, Operand1, Operand2 ]
```

in your example, that means change code to:

```
parseExp( ExpToParse, RES ) :-
    operand(ExpToParse, Diff, Operand1),
    operator(Diff, Diff2, Op),
    operand(Diff2, _, Operand2),
    RES =.. [Op,Operand1, Operand2].
```

Comment: "It is not allowed to write `Op(Operand1, Operand2)` like in:"
Ok. Is there any important casue or only explanation is: It is just Prolog?

Comment: @Gigamesz: It is a restriction in the syntax of prolog. It could be included, but it was not.